# Find the indicial equation of $(x+2)^2(x-1)y''+5(x-1)y'-\pi(x+2)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series

Find all singular points of each equation, and determine whether they are regular or irregular. At each regular singular point, find the indicial equation and the exponents of singularity.

$$(x+2)^2(x-1)y''+5(x-1)y'-\pi(x+2)y = 0$$

The two singular points are $x=-2$ and $x=1$, $x=-2$ is irregular and $x=1$ is regular.

I'm having trouble finding the indicial equation when $x=1$
Here's my work:

Let $y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^{n+r}$ ,

Then $y'=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-1}$

$y''=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-2}$

Plug into the differential equation

$$(x+2)^2(x-1)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-2}+5(x-1)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-1}-\pi(x+2)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^{n+r} = 0$$

Distribute the terms I get

$$(x+2)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-1}+
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 5(n+r)a_n(x-1)^{n+r}-
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \pi xa_n(x-1)^{n+r}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 2 \pi a_n(x-1)^{n+r} = 0$$

My problem is, how do I distribute the $(x+2)^2$ in $(x+2)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)(n+r-1)a_n(x-1)^{n+r-1}$?

Also, is there a short cut way of finding the indicial equation? Or do I always to plug in and do all these index shifting, summations in order to find the indicial equation?